# How do I access user information with django with django-social-auth?

Tags: python, django, oauth

My guess is that I am still able to use the `user` object to get the default information like email or user name. Is this correct?

What if I would like to access some more information not specified on django default `user` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly they just use the default user model. So just like with the default user object you can create a profile model to store additional information.